# Adding react components to header based on the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, children, gatsby

On all but two pages of my site I would like the header to include two buttons. How can I make the header aware of this so it includes the buttons when needed and doesn't for the other two pages. I'm using React and [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/).

Could I accomplish this by adding if statements to my component? If so I'm not sure how to move beyond this step.

```
  const isHomepage = pathname == `/`
  const isContact = pathname == `/contact/`
  let styles = {}
  if (isHomepage) {

    }
  } else if (isContact) {



     } else {
  }
```

This is my code for the header:

```
import React from 'react'
import Link from 'gatsby-link'
import colors from '../utils/colors'

const Header = ({ siteTitle }) => (
  <div
    style={{
      background: colors.white,
      marginBottom: '1.45rem',
      borderBottom: '1px solid',
      borderBottomColor: colors.green,
      height: '3rem',
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      width: '100%',
      position: 'fixed',
    }}
  >
    <div
      style={{
        paddingLeft: 20,
        paddingRight: 20,
        marginLeft: 'auto',
        marginRight: 'auto',
        maxWidth: 960,
      }}
    >
      <div
        style={{
          display: 'flex',
          flexDirection: 'row',
          alignItems: 'center',
          height: 53,
        }}>
        <h3 style={{
          margin: 0,
        }}>
        <Link
          to="/"
          style={{
            color: colors.green,
            textDecoration: 'none',
            fontWeight: 450,
          }}
        >
          {siteTitle}
        </Link>
      </h3>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
)

export default Header
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use conditional rendering based on location.pathname

```
{['/path1', '/path2'].indexOf(location.pathname) === -1 && (
   <button>1<button>
   <button>2<button>
)}
```

```js
import React from 'react'
import Link from 'gatsby-link'
import colors from '../utils/colors'

const Header = ({ siteTitle }) => (
  <div
    style={{
      background: colors.white,
      marginBottom: '1.45rem',
      borderBottom: '1px solid',
      borderBottomColor: colors.green,
      height: '3rem',
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      width: '100%',
      position: 'fixed',
    }}
  >
    <div
      style={{
        paddingLeft: 20,
        paddingRight: 20,
        marginLeft: 'auto',
        marginRight: 'auto',
        maxWidth: 960,
      }}
    >
      <div
        style={{
          display: 'flex',
          flexDirection: 'row',
          alignItems: 'center',
          height: 53,
        }}>
        <h3 style={{
          margin: 0,
        }}>
        <Link
          to="/"
          style={{
            color: colors.green,
            textDecoration: 'none',
            fontWeight: 450,
          }}
        >
          {siteTitle}
        </Link>
        {['/path1', '/path2'].indexOf(location.pathname) === -1 && (
          <button>1<button>
          <button>2<button>
        )}
      </h3>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
)

export default Header
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. How can I make it so the header includes those two buttons on all paths that are not /path1 and /path2. I want the buttons for every page except two.

Comment: Have you read the answer? I answered your question. Now it's your turn  where you want to add those buttons and what kind of buttons you want. Do something by yourself

Comment: I have read and implemented your answer. The buttons appear when the URL includes path1 and path2. Instead of adding every path for which I would like to have those two buttons appear (there are a lot and the number is growing) I would like the buttons to appear for everything but two. Does that make sense?

Comment: Are you using literally my code with this condition `['/path1', '/path2'].indexOf(location.pathname) !== -1`?

Comment: Yes, I am. I didn't want to mess anything up. I'm new to React.

Comment: I deleted the ! from the does not equal and now I think it works. Is there any reason I shouldn't have done that?

Comment: Condition was switched. `!==` means contains path1 or path2